# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when fetching sanity data in client components next 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cors, react-query, sanity

I tried fetching data from Sanity in client component Next 13 using both a client fetching library and vanilla react. It shows this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://rc70arjs.api.sanity.io/v2021-10-21/data/query/production?query=*%5B_type+%3D%3D+%22user%22%5D'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

This is my client config:

```
const client = createClient({
   projectId: 'rc70arjs',
   dataset: 'production',
   apiVersion: '2021-10-21',
   useCdn: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add CORS configuration to sanity.

**Via your management console**

To add a CORS origin from your management console:

1. Go to https://www.sanity.io/manage
2. Pick your project from the list
3. Go to **Settings**, and then to **API settings**
4. Under **CORS Origins**, click the **Add CORS origin** button
5. Enter your **Origin** (http://localhost:3000), select whether or not to **Allow credentials**, and click **Save**. If your origin was added successfully, it will appear at the top of your CORS origins list.

**Via the command line interface**

To add a CORS origin from the CLI:

1. Navigate to your project's folder in your terminal
2. Run the command sanity `cors add [ORIGIN]`, where `[ORIGIN]` meets the requirements listed above
3. When prompted, select whether or not to allow credentials

You can confirm your origin was added with the statement `CORS origin added successfully` or by consulting the list returned by the command sanity cors list.

More details at [Sanity Docs](https://www.sanity.io/docs/cors)